# FreeRTOS debugging with openOCD

Tags: eclipse, gdb, stm32, freertos, openocd

I'm trying to understand what is needed to have kernel aware debugging with openOCD and debug FreeRTOS.
My setup is the following: stm32f401c discovery board, eclipse, openOCD 0.10, gdb. Basically, the SW4STM32 1.8.0 package.

I've already done the following:

- added `$_TARGETNAME configure -rtos auto` to the .cfg file that the openOCD reads
- added FreeRTOS-openocd.c file to the project

Anything else to do? I'm currently receiving the following error from gdb:

```
[New Remote target]
[Switching to Remote target]
Invalid selected thread.
```

Thanks.

**--Update**:

I've found out the issue; the setup doesn't behave well before the RTOS scheduler is started (i.e. in main).
I've modified gdb to halt at the first task and not at main and now it's working.
Can openOCD work before the scheduler is started?

Comment: I've found out the issue; the setup doesn't behave well before the RTOS scheduler is started (i.e. in main).
I've modified the gdb to halt at the first task and not at main and now it's working.

Comment: Hi, would you care to share the change you made to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

Its not running on an STM32 - but perhaps the following will help https://mcuoneclipse.com/2016/04/09/freertos-thread-debugging-with-eclipse-and-openocd/

Comment: That guide is a useful reference. What do you mean that it's not working on STM32?